# rendering exact jpeg file through php

Tags: php, image, gd, jpeg

I am using following code to render a JPEG file, which is on disk, through the imagejpeg function:

```
//.... some headers....
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($the_file);
imagejpeg($image);
```

Now, problem is, [imagejpeg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) compresses the image (reduces the quality in my case) and does not output the same file. I know I can control the quality through a parameter, but it seems that imagejpeg does jpeg encoding/decoding. I don't want that (seems a waste, as the file is already a jpeg file). I want a simple function that will just "RENDER" the image (which is what I thought imagejpeg did till now).  Can someone tell what to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [**`readfile()`**](https://www.php.net/readfile) function, to read the file from the disk, and output its content -- without doing any manipulation / transformation on it.

Comment: hmm... sounds almost too simple, but ya, logical. I have been using  imagepng, imagegif, imagejpeg etc  to render png/gif/jpeg files on disk. Guess thats  inefficient and unnecessary processing?

Comment: Indeed : with those functions you will analyse the content of the file, process it as an image, ... If you just want to output that content, no need to work on it like an image.